# how to create Azure Functions from Azure python sdk?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions, azure-sdk-python

Any examples on how to create Azure Functions with Azure Python SDK ?

is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.web.models.Site?view=azure-python a correct reference for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explicit examples, at my knowledge there is not. But it's definitely using the azure-mgmt-web package you point at. You need to create an AppPlan (or serverfarm), and then a webapp of kind "functionapp".

The closest to an example would probably to look at what the Azure CLI (written in Python) is doing:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/e0c49d6fd4778b8e0c8884a54bca1716a916763e/src/command_modules/azure-cli-appservice/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/custom.py#L1613-L1684